# Limit of an alternating series in a variable not summed over

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

What is

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2\pi)^{2k}(-1)^k (n+1)!}{(n+2k+1)!}?$$

Here $n$ is an integer greater than or equal to $4$.

Comment: Playing around with Wolfy, looks like it might be 1.

Comment: I suspect it is 1 as well, but I don't know how to rigorously prove it.

Comment: It's an alternating series, and for $n \geqslant 4$, the modulus of the terms is strictly decreasing. So you can bound the sum of the series between the first term ($k = 0$) and the sum of the first two terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+2k+1)!}\le\frac1{(n+1)^{2k}}$. Therefore,

$$
\begin{align}
\left|\,\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(2\pi)^{2k}(-1)^k(n+1)!}{(n+2k+1)!}-1\,\right|
&=\left|\,\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(2\pi)^{2k}(-1)^k(n+1)!}{(n+2k+1)!}\,\right|\\
&\le\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(2\pi)^{2k}}{n^{2k}}\\
&=\frac{4\pi^2}{n^2-4\pi^2}
\end{align}
$$
Thus,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(2\pi)^{2k}(-1)^k(n+1)!}{(n+2k+1)!}=1
$$

Comment: Slick! Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Wolfy says that
$n!\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^k}{(n+2k)!}
=_1F_2(1;n/2+1/2, n/2+1;x/4)
$.

According to
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042702006271,
$_1F_2(a; b+r, c+r; z)
\approx (1-z)^{-a}(1+\dfrac{a(r-b)}{c+r}w+O(r^{-2}))
$
where
$w = \dfrac{z}{z-1}$.

Therefore

$\begin{array}\\
_1F_2(1; 1/2+n/2, 1+n/2; z)
&\approx (1-z)^{-1}(1+
\dfrac{1(n/2-1/2)}{1+n/2}w+O(n^{-2}))\\
&= \dfrac1{1-z}(1+
\dfrac{n-1}{n+2}w+O(n^{-2}))\\
&= \dfrac1{1-z}(1+
\dfrac{n-1}{n+2}\dfrac{z}{z-1}+O(n^{-2}))\\
&= \dfrac1{1-z}-
\dfrac{n-1}{n+2}\dfrac{z}{(z-1)^2}+\dfrac1{1-z}O(n^{-2}))\\
&= \dfrac1{1-z}-
\dfrac{z}{(z-1)^2}+O(n^{-1})\\
\end{array}
$

so
$_1F_2(1; 1/2+n/2, 1+n/2; -z)
\approx \dfrac1{1+z}+
\dfrac{z}{(1+z)^2}+O(n^{-1})
\approx \dfrac{1+2z}{(1+z)^2}+O(n^{-1})
$

If $z = 4\pi^2$,
this goes to
$\dfrac{1+\pi^2/2}{(1+4\pi^2)^2}
\sim 0.0036220$.

However, this disagrees 
with computations.

I'll leave it at this.